# Editing files if FTP port isn't available, Port 80 only

Tags: port, editing

I have a remote server using a LAMP stack, and I want to edit files.  Normally, I would use Filezilla or any other FTP client to browse and edit these files.

Unfortunately, sometimes I'm on a network that blocks every outgoing port except 80.

Some of those files happen to be Wordpress theme files using PHP, and sometimes different CMS's give you the ability to edit files through their CMS, like Wordpress > Appearance > Editor.  That got me to thinking... is there something that can edit/save files in a similar system that would keep me on Port 80?

I guess kinda like how most shared host providers have their "File Manager" in account management.

If I can't use the traditional 21, what could I do to still be able to edit these files?  No file transfers would be necessary.

All ideas are welcome.  Many thanks SU.

Comment: cpanel (not free) or webmin (free), but they do not use port 80. Teamviewer (kind of free) has a linux client and it uses port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called [WebDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), been around for years.

Comment: haha sweet.  There we go.